# RDP Client for Ubuntu with Proxy

Tags: proxy, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I'm running a Ubuntu/Win7 dual boot on my laptop and have a Win8.1 machine which I'd like to access via RDP from my Ubuntu system. I found a couple of RDP clients which generally work well, but unfortunately I have to access the Internet through the proxy of my college, which none of them apparently supports. I still have Remmina RDP installed.

I've set the proxy-settings (which also requires authentication) in the `.bashrc` as well as in the `apt.conf`.

How can I get the current client working? is there something around allowing manual proxy configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ remmina
```

Press the button to `create a new desktop file`.

Set up remmina so you can connect to through the GUI.

Save it.

Quit.

Look in your /home/user/.remmina/ directory to a `xxxxxxx.remmina` file.

Edit it:

```
 $ nano /home/user/.remmina/xxxxxxx.remmina
```

Add the following line:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

From the terminal, run it:

```
 $ remmina -c /home/user/.remmina/xxxxxxx.remmina
```

That should have brought up your desktop connection.

Comment: thanks very much, it even works when i start it normally from the GUI :)

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Remmina that file is in `~/.local/share/remmina/xxxxxxxx.remmina`

Answer (score 1):

For "one time" solution, you can also use:
`export https_proxy="socks5://host:port" && remmina`

Some other options are mentioned in old issue related to proxy https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2046

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the flatpack version of Remina you can add the env variable mentioned in other answers easily via Flatseal. Just click the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the `Environment` section and add you proxy directly:

`https_proxy=socks5://host:port`

This allowed me to connect to the VPN connection of my phone using a SOCKS
proxy via [Every Proxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gorillasoftware.everyproxy) since the VPN I needed for work does not have a Linux client but they do have an Android app (looking at you Palo Alto Networks GlobalProtect...).

Comment: Searching for "Flatseat Linux" doesn't give me any good results. It doesn't seem to be [packaged for Ubuntu either](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=flatseat). Since that is the only new contribution in this answer, please expand on what it is and how to get it on Ubuntu. The only link the post seems to be for an Android app, feels a bit spammy.

Comment: I had a typo. Thanks for poiting it out.